# Change button size in vpython on Pydroid

Tags: vpython, pydroid

I have the following code in Pydroid. I creates 3D text in Python on Android. I need to make the button bigger.

```
import asyncio
from vpython import *

scene = canvas()

scene.width = 1600
scene.height = 1600

text(text = "Hello World", align = "center")

def capture_scene():
    img = scene.capture("image")

button(bind=capture_scene, text='Download')

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

Comment: The asyncio code is for this error in case anyone is searching the internet - "cannot schedule new futures after shutdown"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked for me. Instead of trying to change the button and its font. I discovered that I could inject html in the button text.

```
button(bind=capture_scene, text="""<span style="font-size: 63px;"><h1 style="display: inline-block;margin:0;padding:23px;">Download</h1></span>""")
```